# How to use certificate to sign id token in AAD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Recently, I was looking for a way to sign id tokens in Azure AD B2C using certificates. I found that we have to use custom policy to do this.

Here is how to do it.

1. Upload a pfx file (Ex. B2C_1A_signing) to "**Policy Keys**" through "Identity Experience Framework".
2. Override the token issuer claims provider in your relying party policy. If you are using Active Directory B2C Custom Policy Starterpack, you can overwrite `TrustFrameworkBase.xml` by default.

```xml
 <ClaimsProvider>
   <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
   <TechnicalProfiles>
     <TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
       <DisplayName>JWT Issuer</DisplayName>
       <CryptographicKeys>
         <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_signing" />
       </CryptographicKeys>
     </TechnicalProfile>
   </TechnicalProfiles>
 </ClaimsProvider>
```

Notice that the issuer_secret is changed to reference the storage reference id of the certificate.

3. Check metadata

```
{
  "keys": [
    {"kid":"E62C82DD3E3CED17DFE23D0FFB837E46C5B36182","exp":4652954830,"nbf":1497280630,"key_ops":["sign"],"x5c":["<Certificate>"}
  ]
}
```

Kid references the thumbprint of the cert and the cert is listed as x5c.

4. Send an authentication request.

```
{
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "E62C82DD3E3CED17DFE23D0FFB837E46C5B36182",
    "x5t": "5iyC3T487Rff4j0P-4N-RsWzYYI"
}.{
    "exp": 1505922183,
    "nbf": 1505918583,
    "ver": "1.0",
    "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/v2.0/",
    "sub": "<>",
    "aud": "<>",
    "acr": "b2c_1a_signup_signin",
    "nonce": "defaultNonce",
    "iat": 1505918583,
    "auth_time": 1505918583,
    "name": "Chi Yao"
}.[Signature]
```

Comment: You may want to convert this into a Q&A format. The question would be how to sign tokens using certificates, and the text you have currently in the question would actually be the answer.

Comment: You may want to also use TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml, which will override the StorageReferenceId. This will make it easier to manage because in the future, when you apply a new TrustFrameworkBase with a more recent version of the starter pack, it will not wash away your settings.